# How can we plot quadrilateral (all known length) in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have a quadrilateral (piece of land) of known side lengths. How can we plot it ( using geom_point/geom_poly) in ggplot?

- The measurements are: AB = 11.55, BC = 17.17, CD = 11.77, DA = 15.76
- Diagonal: BD = 20.20,  AC = 20.34
- A can be set as origin. We can assume AB is along x axis.

Edit 1 -
The quadrilateral has four landmarks in each corner. I found the distances from google map (using measure distance). Now, I want to plot this quadrilateral on ggplot.

Edit 2 -
There is no unique quadrilateral. The measured distance may not be very accurate (plus/minus 0.5 meter)

Comment: [Is this homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) ? What did you try so far?

Comment: No. The quadrilateral has four landmarks in each corner. I found the distances from google map (using measure distance). Now, I want to plot this quadrilateral on ggplot.

Comment: A quadrilateral is not uniquely determined by its side lengths. You need more information.

Comment: If you get the diagonal lengths, AC and BD, that would be sufficient.

Comment: That is good suggestion. I understand there is no unique quadrilateral. We can fix AB along x axis

Comment: Fixing a single line along a single axis is arbitrary - it only uniquely determines two points. Unless you have diagonal measurements or corner angle measurements there are still infinitely many quadrilaterals with those side lengths with all sorts of different angles.

Comment: This is, for example [why you measure diagonals to check if a rectangle has right angles](https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/FVP/0SIT/G2L3C0GF/FVP0SITG2L3C0GF.png?auto=webp&frame=1&fit=bounds&md=7c9596218d4e1fa9f779f3c74942dafa) in woodworking/construction/crafting. Knowing the side lengths is not enough to know the angles. The two quadrilaterals in the linked picture have the same side lengths, but the shapes are very different because the diagonals and corner angles are very different.

Comment: The simplest solution of all is to use coordinates. You said you're using google maps - instead of measuring distance, record the exact latitude and longitude. ggplot can plot those latitude and longitude directly, instead of giving you a geometry problem to solve to find (x, y) coordinates from side lengths. You can still label the sides with the lengths you measured.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes lot of sense. I can record coordinates and convert them into local coordinates.

Comment: You can also record coordinates and not convert them at all - `ggplot` can handle latitude/longitude.